# Is there a way to quickly identify the range of a formula from a cell in the range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been trying to Google what I want, but is not able to find the right page for me.

Here is my question.

We all know that in Excel, you can apply a formula to a range of cells.

Now I am given a Excel spreadsheet and I want to be able to find out the range a formula is applied to from a cell within the range ?

Is there a quick way to do so please?

For example:
Assume that the cells A1, A2, B1 and B2 together hold the result when applying a formula F (using control + shift +enter). My question is that, if I am on cell A1, how can I know that A2, B1 and B2 are also part of the same result from F?

Comment: are you asking about using formula auditing (under the formula menu) to trace precedents/dependents?

Comment: If you mean you want to find all cells where a given formula is present, I,m not sure there's an easy way to do that. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your question is not making a lot of sense.  Maybe a table and a formula demonstrating what you are out to accomplish will help.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat an example is given. hopefully that makes it clearer. this problem is hard to describe otherwise I would not be asking it here (as I would have found the result from google) . thanks for your patience.

Comment: Are you looking for Find feature in Excel? You can enter the FUNCTION and Look in: Formulas and then you can get all Result you need in list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMUjd.png

Comment: You could probably do a macro, but A1 could be involved in many formulas.  It's a good question, tho.

Comment: So, you want to show the range where is an Array Formula placed? You can try to use keyboard shortcut ``CTRL``+ `` ` `` to show formulas instead results. (Shortcut could be different in non-English versions. See [help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-and-print-formulas-65a29965-b1b1-40db-9cb7-4fd051da3a5c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US))

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with this short macro.

```vb
Public Sub SelectArrayRange()
    With Selection
        If .HasArray Then
            .CurrentArray.Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

It checks if selected cell contains an array formula. If yes, it selects whole range of this array formula. Does nothing when multiple cells are selected (one exception is when the whole area is a part of the same array function).

You can run this macro by a custom keyboard shortcut. See chapters **Before you run macros** and **Run a macro by pressing a combination shortcut key** on [Excel support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155) for details